# Limit number of results in, or remove, attributechip from hmc admin tab

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a list relation within one of my items in Hybris. This list is not necessary to display in the HMC admin tab and is causing long load times when viewing the item.

I'm having difficulty trying to limit the number of results displayed or remove the particular attributechip from the HMC all together using the hmc.xml.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
<relation code="Favorite2ProductRelation" localized="false"
      generate="true" autocreate="true">
<sourceElement type="Favorite" qualifier="favorite"
               cardinality="many">
    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" />
    <custom-properties>
        <property name="hiddenForUI">
            <value>Boolean.TRUE</value>
        </property>
    </custom-properties>
</sourceElement>
<targetElement type="Product" qualifier="product"
               cardinality="one">
    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" initial="true"
               optional="false" />
</targetElement>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the attribute definition you can set the property `hiddenForUI`, it will hide the field from bo :

```
<attribute ...>
    <custom-properties>
        <property name="hiddenForUI">
            <value>Boolean.TRUE</value>
        </property>
    </custom-properties>
</attribute>
```

However it seems that it can't be used in relation...

You can switch the attribute value using impex :

```
INSERT_UPDATE RelationDescriptor;qualifier[unique=true];hiddenForUI[default=true]
;<attributeOfYourRelationToHide>;
```

If you have an attribute name present in different objects, you can specify which object you working on with `enclosingType` (thanks to Mouad El Fakir for the recall)

```
INSERT_UPDATE RelationDescriptor;enclosingType(code)[unique=true];qualifier[unique=true];hiddenForUI[default=true]
;<objectHoldingTheAttributeToHide>;<attributeOfYourRelationToHide>;
```

Comment: The attribute in question is defined as a relation in the items.xml and hence not possible to use hiddenForUI as far as I'm aware?

Comment: You can set it in the `sourceElement` or `targetElement` tags according to the xsd.

Comment: Seems to have no effect in HMC even though it is valid according to the xsd. Please see the attached snippet in my initial post and let me know if I'm going wrong somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it has no effect on relation, that's probably a bug... I've managed to hide it by changing the property from the "type" admin though. You can achive it using impex : `INSERT_UPDATE RelationDescriptor;qualifier[unique=true];hiddenForUI[default=true]
;targetName;`

Comment: Yes, that's great. Thanks.

Comment: @alain.janinm i think you need to add `enclosingType(code)[unique=true]` to the impex